# Data Validation in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, validation

In my theme, i am grabbing user input with get_option() and according to that input i want to i want to declare a new variable and print in my single.php file. For example:

```
<?php
$tutorial_condition = get_option( 'tutorials_creater' );

if ( $tutorial_condition == 1 ) {
    $second_col_class = 'col-9';
} else {
    $second_col_class = 'col-2';
}
?>
```

now when i echo $second_col_class variable in my php files it works fine. But when i run themecheck plugin it shows an error like this.

"Possible data validation issues found. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered."

i want to echo that variable like below.

```
 <div class="<?php echo $second_col_class; ?>">
     //my code here..
 </div>
```

I cannot use isset() function because it just returning true or false. Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this Codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) for further guide, but in your case, you would use [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) to escape the `$second_col_class` value which is being used in an HTML attribute, namely `class`:

```html
<!-- bad -->
<div class="<?php echo $second_col_class; ?>">

<!-- good -->
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $second_col_class ); ?>">

<!-- good -->
<div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $second_col_class, 'text-domain' ); ?>">
```

Comment: Problem solved.thanks. But even this variable value is not a user input, why WordPress recommend to use esc_attr() function.

Comment: Because it's a good practice to *always escape* values that are *dynamic*, e.g. strings assigned to a variable like your `$second_col_class` - what if someone edited your code and changed the value to a dynamic one, like another variable? And if my answer answered the question, please consider marking the answer as correct. =) Thanks!

Comment: If you're specifically asking about the `esc_attr()`, then as I said in my answer and by the function's purpose itself, WordPress recommends using it because that's one of the correct functions we should use for escaping HTML attributes like `class`, `title` and `src`. :)